# Add DLL and control from code dynamicly

Tags: windows, vba, dll, com

The situation:

There are serveral macros for each version of program XYZ, at each update the developers of XYZ are providing a new .dll with some COM controls. The problem is that you have to rebuild the macro for every new version. (current)

Is there a way at VBA to add this .dll by code and add the control also by code? Maybe add a dummy control and replace it at every start with the real control? Can someone provide me a example maybe?

I'm looking forward to your answers, thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you need to update the *Reference* to the DLL each time?  If so the alternative to that is to use *late binding* instead of *early binding* using [`CreateObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264813.aspx).

Comment: Yes there are ways to update the references dynamically, but I agree with @AlexK., late binding shoud be a better choice since the dll changes so frequently.

Comment: Ah ok, late binding could be good solution, I thought this doenst work with vba. I will take a look into it and try it. Thanks